# How to display hint text in two sides of editText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

[image]

As you can see 'email' and 'example@abc.com' are on both ends of the `EditText`.At first, I want to use hint to solve it as follow:

```
     android:hint=" email           example@abc.com"
```

but I think it is a bad method. Is there some good ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Using simply hint, I don't think it is possible. Wrap your edit text inside a framelayout and for right side hint, use a textview and add a textwatcher to your edit text. Then as soon as user starts typing, set visibility of that textview to gone

Comment: Hello Vivek Mishra, you solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to display hint text in two sides of editText?

**AFAIK** that is not built in behavior of `editText`, you can achive your required output using single `editText`

> SOLUTIION

Take a `LinearLayout` and wrap a `EditText` and `TextView` inside `LinearLayout`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="nilesh@mail.com" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: using your ways, 'email' can always be visibly. But I want it disvisible when I edit the text.

Comment: @PigChou than you need to add `TextWatcher` to your `edittext` when your editext  is empty text hint on textview

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nilesh Rathod.